# Why does my PageableListView & PagingNavigation not work?

Tags: wicket

I try to use a PageableListView with PagingNavigation. From the examples that looks quite easy, but I can't get it to work. I always get the following error message:

> The component(s) below failed to
>   render. A common problem is that you
>   have added a component in code but
>   forgot to reference it in the markup

Here is my java code:

```
class FriendsPanel extends Panel {
public FriendsPanel(String id){
    super(id);

    List<User> friends = ...;

        PageableListView<User> listview = new PageableListView<User>("listview", friends, 10) {
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> item) {
                User user = item.getModel().getObject();
                item.add(new Label("label", user.getName()));
            }
        };

        add(listview);
        add(new PagingNavigation("navigator", listview));
    }
}
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
  <wicket:panel>
    <br />
    <span wicket:id="listview">
        <span wicket:id="label">label</span><br>
    </span>
    <div wicket:id="navigator"></div>
  </wicket:panel>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: You're missing the trailing slash from your <br />, by the way.

Comment: @ireddick: I code HTML not XHTML, so that is toally legal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PagingNavigation doesn't supply any markup. If you want to use it, you'll have to supply markup for the 'pageLink' and 'pageNumber' components. [The javadoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/navigation/paging/PagingNavigation.html) indicates how they should be laid out.

The confusingly-named [PagingNavigator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/navigation/paging/PagingNavigator.html) is a default version of the above that you can just drop straight in (it's a panel that contains a PagingNavigation). You probably want to just use that.

Comment: Yes, you are right I have to use PagingNavigator instead of PagingNavigation or provide aditional markup. Thanks a lot.